# Azure Logic App - Get Tenant Name without Authentication

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have gathered the tenantid, but I want to convert this to the tenant name. I am using Logic Apps by the way. The tenant name (FDQN) I want to save into a variable.

Is there any way to do this?

Situation:

1. From Sentinel I get the Subscription ID from the tenant. I will save this subscription ID into a variable.
2. From another playbook that gets the tenant ID by providing the subscription ID from Sentinel.
3. The final step would be having that tenant ID and translate/convert it into the FDQN of the tenant. But I do not have the code for that. Also I want to know if it can be found without authenticating. Else I have to find an alternative.

Comment: There is only one tenant name (static) per tenant id, you could save it in the Logic App variable or parameter

Comment: Yes, but how do I translate the tenant ID to the tenant name without performing authentication. I could just be a simple REST request without authentication. I am struggling with it, because I do see that you can convert FDQN to tenant ID, but not the other way around without authenticating. 

PS: Please look at the situation for an elaboration of the problem I am struggling with.

Comment: How do you convert FDQN to tenant ID, any references or examples?

Comment: I want to convert tentant ID to FDQN (The tenant name example contoso.microsoft.com or contoso.com).

Comment: `because I do see that you can convert FDQN to tenant ID` - how do you convert this?

Comment: My bad I meant there the Subscription ID. FDQN to Tenant ID can be done via here: https://www.whatismytenantid.com/

Comment: just to be clear here, you should refer `contoso.com` as the domain name, not FDQN.

Comment: secondly, you are doing this manually, meaning you are going to https://www.whatismytenantid.com/ and entering the domain name and you are getting the tenant ID, to do this in Logic App you need REST API or something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't tenant name from the tenant id without authentication.

But you can use [Microsoft Graph REST API - Get tenant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/managedtenants-tenant-get?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) to get tenant details. Similarly, should be possible with PowerShell, and Azure CLI but you won't use it in Logic App.

`"defaultDomainName": "fourthcoffe001.onmicrosoft.com",`